# Why the data is getting entered twice?

Tags: c++

I am a student still learning C++ and am just a beginner.Here is my code.The problem here is that the last username and password is getting saved twice in text file.Although i have used system to open my other programs because i am just a beginner and this was the easiest way i could figure out.Thanks in advance for the help.

```
// Projectregus.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.


#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<time.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
ifstream users;
class usersdet
{
  public:
char username[100];
char password[100];
double score;
void assignpass(char pass[])
 {
    int k;
    for (int j = 0; pass[j] != '\0'; ++j)
    {
        password[j] = pass[j];
            k = j;
    };
    password[k+1] = '\0';
 }
}A,B,C;
  class quiz
{
  public:
char question[10000];
char option1[1000];
char option2[1000];
char option3[1000];
char option4[1000];
char answer;
};
 /* ***************************************Function login() defination begins here**************************************** */
 void login() 
  {
   cout << "Sign In to continue....\nEnter your username:";
   cin >> B.username;
   int flag = 0, choice;
   users.open("E:\\Users\\Utkarsh\\Documents\\Visual Studio    2015\\Projects\\Project\\Debug\\userdat.txt", ios::in|ios::binary);
if (!users.is_open())
{
    cout << "fatal error!";
    exit(0);
}
while (!users.eof())
{
    users.read((char *)&A, sizeof(A));
    if (strcmp(A.username, B.username) == 0)
    {
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
    else flag = 0;
};
if (flag == 0)
{
    cout << "Account not found!";
    cout << "\nMENU:\n1.Want to make new account?\t2.Retry?";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:system("start E:\\Users\\Utkarsh\\Documents\\Projectnewus.exe");
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 2:system("start E:\\Users\\Utkarsh\\Documents\\projectregus.exe");
        exit(0);
        break;
    default: cout << "Wrong input!";
        exit(0);
    }
}
cout << "Enter password:";
char pass[100];
int i = 0;
char a;
for (i = 0;;)
{
    a = _getch();
    if ((a>='a' && a<='z') || (a>='A'&&a <='Z') || (a>='0'&& a<='9'))
    {
        pass[i] = a;
        ++i;
        cout << "*";
    }
    if (a =='\b' && i>= 1)
    {
        cout << "\b \b";//rub the character behind the cursor.
        --i;
    }
    if (a == '\r')//if enter is pressed
    {
        pass[i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
}
cout << endl;
B.assignpass(pass);
if (strcmp(A.password, B.password) == 0)
{
    cout << "Login successful!";
    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
}
else
{
    cout << "Login failure !";
    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
    exit(0);
    }
  users.close();
 }
    /* *********************************QUIZGAME function defination     here**************************************************** */
   void quizgame()
  {
     B.score = 0;
     cout << "\nLets begin the QUIZ " << A.username;
     cout << "\n Your last score was:" << A.score;
     getchar();
     ifstream game; 
     cout << "Which quiz do you want to play?\n1.General Knowledge\n2.General Science\n";
     int choice2;
     cin >> choice2;
     cin.ignore();
     switch (choice2)           //choice of file to be opened
     {
case 1:game.open("E:\\Users\\Utkarsh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Project\\Debug\\quizGK.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!game.is_open())
    {
        cout << "fatal error!";
        exit(0);
    }
    break;
case 2:game.open("E:\\Users\\Utkarsh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Project\\Debug\\quizGS.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!game.is_open())
    {
        cout << "fatal error!";
        exit(0);
    }
    break;
default:cout << "Wrong input!!";
    exit(0);
};
quiz X;
int qno, seedval, count, verification[50], verificationflag = 1, iotemp = 0, ioflag = 0, gamecounter = 0;
for (int in = 0; in < 6; ++in)          //initialises verification[]
    verification[in] = 0;
char choice1 = 'y';
time_t t;
seedval = (unsigned)time(&t);
srand(seedval);
while (choice1 == 'y'&& gamecounter != 6)
{
    while (verificationflag == 1)           //Assures unique question
    {
        qno = (rand() % 6) + 1;

        for (int io = 0; io < 6; ++io)
        {
            if (verification[io] == qno)
            {
                ioflag = 1;
            }
        }

        if (ioflag == 0)
        {
            verification[iotemp] = qno;
            verificationflag = 0;
            ++iotemp;
        }
        ioflag = 0;

    }

    game.seekg(0);
    for (count = 0; count < qno; ++count)
    {
        game.read((char *)&X, sizeof(X));
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << "Your " << gamecounter + 1 << " Question\n\n";
    cout << X.question << endl << X.option1 << endl << X.option2 << endl << X.option3 << endl << X.option4 << endl << "Enter answer:";
    char answer;
    int score = 0;
    cin >> answer;
    cin.ignore();
    if ((answer == X.answer) || (answer == tolower(X.answer)))
    {
        cout << "correct answer";
        ++B.score;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Wrong answer/nCorrect answer is "<<X.answer;

    }
    cout << "\nYour current score:" << B.score;
    cout << "\nWant to play more?(y/n)";
    cin >> choice1;
    verificationflag = 1;
    ++gamecounter;
    if (gamecounter == 6)
        cout << "GAME ENDED!";

   }
   game.close();
 }
  /* ********************************************MAIN BEGINS     HERE******************************************************** */
 void main() 
{
system("cls");
login();
system("cls");
quizgame();
users.open("E:\\Users\\Utkarsh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Project\\Debug\\userdat.txt", ios::in|ios::binary);
ofstream temp;
temp.open("E:\\Users\\Utkarsh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Project\\Debug\\temp.txt",ios::out|ios::binary);
if (!temp.is_open())
{
    cout << "fatal error!";
    exit(0);
}
if (!users.is_open())
{
    cout << "fatal error!";
    exit(0);
}
users.seekg(0);
while (!users.fail())
{
    users.read((char*)&C, sizeof(C));
    if (strcmp(C.username, A.username) != 0)
        temp.write((char*)&C, sizeof(C));
}
A.score = B.score;
temp.write((char*)&A, sizeof(A));
users.close();
temp.close();
cout << A.username << endl << A.password << endl << A.score;
remove("E:\\Users\\Utkarsh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Project\\Debug\\userdat.txt");
rename("E:\\Users\\Utkarsh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Project\\Debug\\temp.txt", "E:\\Users\\Utkarsh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Project\\Debug\\userdat.txt");
system("pause");


}






 what i am getting in my text file is:
muskaan ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌmuskaan23 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ        sample ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌsample23 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ        sample ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌsample23 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ        utkarsh ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌutkarsh23 ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ      ð?
  Here muskaan,utkarsh and sample is username i entered using another program
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. And better code formatting is always appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting the `eof` function to predict the future and tell you whether a future read will succeed or fail. Unfortunately, that function only reports on the past.

Say you have a list "apple", "orange", "pear". You read "apple" and process it. You read "orange" and process it. You read "pear" and process it. You then try to read again, and fail. But you don't check if the read succeeded, so you process "pear" again. *Then* you break out of the loop because you hit the end of the file.

Forget checking eof. It's not useful. Instead, break out of the loop when a read fails. And, of course, if a read fails, *don't* process the stale data in your buffer that you already processed in the previous read.